# Dynamically displaying Bootstrap Classes in ng2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to display dynamic classes for Bootstrap alerts by using Angular 2.

If the `MessageType` is 1, I want to display Success message and 2 for Error message.  Please see the sample below

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  Your data has been saved successfully.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  Error occurred!!!  Try again.
</div>
```

I tried to do the dynamic class like the following, but it doesn't work at all:

```
<div [ngClass]="['alert', 'alert-success': MessageType == 1, 'alert-danger' : MessageType == 2]" *ngIf="Message">
    {{Message}}
</div>
```

**add-todo.component.ts**

```
export class TodoAddComponent {

    Message: string;
    MessageType: number;


    AddItem(): void {

        // do some processing

        this.Message = "New Item has been added";
        this.MessageType = 1;
    }
}
```

How can I display the class 'alert-success' or 'alert-danger' dynamically in the Html?  Should I do it like this according to the result and use it back in html?

```
alertClass: string;
this.alertClass = 'alert-success'; // if it succeeds

this.alertClass = 'alert-danger'; // if it fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an object to `[ngClass]` instead of an array, because right now you're trying to pass invalid array-object hybrid.

Use array to just tell which classes you want to use.

Use object to include conditions making specific classes appear/disappear.

```
<div [ngClass]="{alert: true, 'alert-success': MessageType == 1, 'alert-danger': MessageType == 2 }" *ngIf="Message">
    {{Message}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also bind directly to class with the required alert-x class:

```
<div *ngIf="Message"
      class="alert"
     [class.alert-success]="MessageType == 1"
     [class.alert-danger]="MessageType == 2">
   {{Message}}
</div>
```

Comment: I misunderstood about this syntax due to this article https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/  It is saying that it's used to add a single class.  Since I am adding 2 classes 'alert' and 'alert-xxx', I didn't try... how silly I am.

Comment: No worries. I like the [class.xxx] syntax, (I think) it's a bit easier to read.
I'm also using bootstrap and have found I use this syntax a lot as you have a class you always want present e.g. 'btn' or 'alert', and you want to append other classes based on some binding.